# IntelliJ not saving cookies

Tags: intellij-idea, cookies, httprequest

I'm working with an endpoint in my code base from the IntelliJ HTTP client. For example, I do this:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/path/to/my/endpoint/
```

The response has a `Set-Cookie` header and according to the IntelliJ documentation:

> The cookies received through a response are automatically saved into the dedicated http-client.cookies file under the .idea/httpRequests/ directory. The number of cookies that can be saved is limited to 300. The name and value of a cookie are automatically included in each subsequent request to the URL that matches the domain and path specified for the cookie, provided that the expiry date has not been reached.

However, when I run my request then open `http-client.cookies` all I see is this:

```
# domain    path    name    value   date
```

What gives here? Is this feature broken?

P.S. I am on the most recent stable version as of this writing, 2020.3.2, on Mac OS X.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156476 could be the case. If it's not, feel free to file a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder `expires=Tue, 08 Feb 2022 20:08:55 GMT;`. Yup, looks like that might be th eissue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder will you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [a known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156476) related to the format of the cookie expire date.